# ¿Cómo puedo poner la función de pedir permisos para la cámara al hacer clic en un botón de bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Tengo este código:

```
<header>
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-content-inner">
            <h1>Por favor, verifica que no eres un robot.</h1>
            <p>Este es un sitio web de WhatsApp Inc.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Dale clic en "Permitir"</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Quiero que al hacer clic en el botón pida permisos de acceso a la cámara como en la siguiente imagen... [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] y si no se puede esto, entonces que al hacer clic se recargue la página. Gracias

Comment: Tengo que preguntar por curiosidad: ¿qué estás construyendo? Porque "verifica que no eres un robot" dando permisos para la cámara y que pueda verse al usuario abre la puerta a muchas preguntas de seguridad, privacidad y ética.

Comment: Hola, sí claro, te diré. soy nuevo en este mundo y me interesa mucho aprender estos lenguajes. estoy intentando hacer algo así como saycheese, sólo que el index de saycheese no me parece muy confiable para mi intención. Me gusta mucho este mundo y pues intento hacer esto por sólo un motivo, quiero tener información de un tipo que está acosando y extorsionando a mi madre desde hace unos meses, las autoridades no han hecho nada y personas con las que he hablado me cobran mucho dinero por darme esa información. Así que quise intentarlo por mi mismo.

Answer (score 0):

debes usar esta funcion getUserMedia() es una promesa usa asycn o then

```
<button onClick={() => {
var p = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });

p.then(function(mediaStream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    // Do something with the video here.
  };
});

p.catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name); }); // always check for errors at the end.
```

}}>camara

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe qué hace `getUserMedia()`. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.